# CSS - media query in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, media-queries

I am working on a responsive template and using CSS media query. but seems IE7 doesn't support media query directly. so I looked for solution and found [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)
but I can't make it work.

***HTML:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

   <!-- ... -->

</body>
</html>
```

***CSS (style.css):***

```
@import "reset.css";
@import "fonts.css";
@import "bootstrap.css";
@import "plugins.css";
@import "ui.css";

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) { 
    /* css */
}
```

but when I include the `@media screen and (max-width: 320px) { }` directly in my HTML its working.
So what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

respond.js specifically states it can't parse media queries included via @import

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

> "Respond.js doesn't parse CSS refrenced via @import, nor does it work
>   with media queries within style elements, as those styles can't be
>   re-requested for parsing."

Comment: the media queries that I used are not included via @import. they are in `styles.css` which included by `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />`
and those `@import` css's have nothing with media queries.

Comment: Your styles css file is using import.  unfortunately, any use whatsoever of @import inside any of your css breaks respond.js in IE < 9.  If you can swing it, start using SASS. You can include stuff which has the same result in the end as import but it doesn't cause issues with respond.js