# Css Media Query - IE 7 not load

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, media-queries

I have this prestashop (http://www.cavan.com/)

I have loaded some CSS for Responsive.

In Firefox it works correctly, and in Internet Explorer 10 also.

But in "Compatibility View" in Internet Explorer 10 and in Internet Explorer 7, not working, not loading media Query

Could anyone tell me why it can be?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: I have an important message for you Javier: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - media query in IE7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202148/css-media-query-in-ie7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS media queries are only supported in IE9+.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries